# Android - registerReceiver / multiple action

Tags: android

I have a question about registerReceiver and addAction.

Let's say that I have a servide, which runs in an activity (via a start button). This service will register a receiver via registerReceiver. There is something like that in the onStartcommand() method of the service :

```
final IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter();
filter1.addAction(ACTION_1); // The ACTION is defined in my code
this.br_receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();  // The class is defined in my code
this.registerReceiver(this.br_receiver, filter1);
return (START_STICKY);
```

Now, let's say that I have three different ACTIONS and three checkboxes (one for each ACTION). When I press the button, it starts the service which checks which ACTIONS it has to add via addAction method(). Of course there is a stop button.

**My question :** when I use the unregisterReceiver() method how can I stop handling only the ACTION I want (I know which ones thanks to the checkbox checked before clicking onto the stop button) ?

I am not sure I am clear so I am going to explain it in a different way : I know that one solution would be to add all the ACTIONS (addAction) when I start the service and then, in the onReceive method(), I could use three boolean in order to know what ACTION to take care of. I think this solution is crappy.

Sholuld I use different IntentFilter, one for each ACTION ? If yes, how ?

If you have anwser or even an advice, you're welcome !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> My question : when I use the unregisterReceiver() method how can I stop handling only the ACTION I want (I know which ones thanks to the checkbox checked before clicking onto the stop button) ?

Option #1: Register three receivers, one per action, and unregister the one for the action that the user unchecks.

Option #2: Register for only those actions that the user has checked, and when the user changes the checked/unchecked state of a checkbox, unregister and re-register the receiver.

Comment: Thanks. Still one question (just because you gave me two good solutions !) : The first option is obvious but requieres three receivers. The second option is simple and ask to unregister/register receiver with correct ACTIONS. Which one is the best (the first requieres more code, that's the only point) ? I can't determine it !

Comment: @frontal: Off the top of my head, I couldn't tell you. I doubt either is dramatically longer than the other.

Comment: Indeed, we can say that :) I only think about optimization and CPU charge.

Comment: @frontal: Oh, from those aspects, there's not going to be a big difference, either.

Comment: Ok, let's rock n roll. Thanks a lot.